# How can I restrict Drag & Drop at the same level in Liquor Tree?

Tags: vue.js

Currently, I'm using a liquor tree (library) for drag and drop the nodes.

What I want in this to restrict the user so that they are not able to drag and drop the node from one parent to another.

Ex: User can not drag and drop MVP Pattern inside the Patterns or The Good Parts shown in the above fiddle.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gqj9bvmw/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag & Drop</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/liquor-tree"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <tree
      :data="treeData"
      :options="treeOptions"
      @node:dragging:start="logDragStart"
      @node:dragging:finish="logDragFinish"
    />
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
          treeData: getTreeData(),
          treeOptions: {
            propertyNames: {
              text: 'MY_TEXT',
              children: 'KIDS',
              state: 'OPTIONS'
            },
            dnd: true,
            checkbox: true
          }
        }),
        
        methods: {
            logDragStart(node) {
            console.log('Start dragging: ' + node.text)
          },
          
            logDragFinish(targetNode, distinationNode) {
            console.log(`Stop dragging: [TARGET]${targetNode.text}`)
          }
        }
      })

      function getTreeData() {
        return [
          {
            MY_TEXT: 'JS: The Right Way',
            OPTIONS: { expanded: true },
            KIDS: [
              { MY_TEXT: 'Getting Started (NOT DRAGGABLE)', OPTIONS: { checked: true, draggable: false } },
              { MY_TEXT: 'JavaScript Code Style', OPTIONS: { selected: true } },
              { MY_TEXT: 'MVC Pattern (NOT DROPABLE)', OPTIONS: {dropable: false} },
              { MY_TEXT: 'MVP Pattern' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'MVVM Pattern' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'The Good Parts', KIDS: [
                { MY_TEXT: 'OBJECT ORIENTED', OPTIONS: { checked: true }  },
                { MY_TEXT: 'ANONYMOUS FUNCTIONS', OPTIONS: { checked: true }  },
                { MY_TEXT: 'FUNCTIONS AS FIRST-CLASS OBJECTS', OPTIONS: { checked: true }  },
                { MY_TEXT: 'LOOSE TYPING', OPTIONS: { checked: true }  }
              ]},
              { MY_TEXT: 'Patterns', KIDS: [
                { MY_TEXT: 'DESIGN PATTERNS', OPTIONS: { expanded: true }, KIDS: [
                  { MY_TEXT: 'Creational Design Patterns', KIDS: [
                    { MY_TEXT: 'Factory' },
                    { MY_TEXT: 'Prototype' },
                    { MY_TEXT: 'Mixin' },
                    { MY_TEXT: 'Singleton' }
                  ]},
                  { MY_TEXT: 'Structural Design Patterns'}
                ]},
                { MY_TEXT: 'MV* PATTERNS', cildren: [
                  { MY_TEXT: 'MVC Pattern' },
                  { MY_TEXT: 'MVP Pattern' },
                  { MY_TEXT: 'MVVM Pattern' }
                ]}
              ]}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The below link contains the documentation for this

[LiquorTree](https://amsik.github.io/liquor-tree/#Drag-amp-Drop)

Comment: Please post the code necessary to understand/reproduce your situation *here*.

Comment: @deceze - I have added the code and also it's available on fiddle link. what I want to do in this have mentioned already i.e drag and drop is restricted at the same level